# Simple arithmetic advice

Tags: c#

I have started using c# for the first time, today. I recently been using Delphi Quite a lot.

Anyways, I tried to make a program that checks if your marks are equal to or greater than 75%, if so, the label will caption `You shall receive a bursary!`, and so on.. There are three text boxes for three different sets of marks, namely IT, Maths and Science. They are all out of 150.

Here's the arithmetic:

```
Average = (((Maths/150)*100)+((IT/150)*100)+((Science/150)*100))/3;
```

The problem is, the label doesn't display anything at all if all the given marks are `140/150` which = 93%, it shouldn't display anything if its bellow 75%.

The rest of my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Name;
            string Surname;
            int Maths;
            int Science;
            int IT;
            float Average;


            Name = edtName.Text;
            Surname = edtSurname.Text;
            Maths = int.Parse(edtMaths.Text);
            Science = int.Parse(edtScience.Text);
            IT = int.Parse(edtIT.Text);
            Average = (((Maths/150)*100)+((IT/150)*100)+((Science/150)*100))/3;

            if (Average >= 75)
            {
                lblOutput.Text += "You shall recieve a bursary!";
            }
```

Please help me correct what I'm doing wrong,

thanks :)

Comment: You should break up your math equation into multiple parts and use the debugger (our output to console) to allow you to see whats happening.

Comment: You should definitely take a deeper look at databinding, objects and properties, it would make your life a lot easier! Btw: you should empty your label when Average < 75. You can extend your if statement with an else and set lblOutput.Text = "";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have integer arithmetics, division of `140/150` gives you `0`.

From C# [7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Integer division:

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

If you want to have 90% (i.e. 0.9) then you should use floating-point division:

```
Average = (((Maths/150F)*100)+((IT/150F)*100)+((Science/150F)*100))/3;
```

Also I suggest to create named constant(s) which explain 150 magic number(s).

Comment: Much appreciated Sergey!

Answer (score 3):

Because what you done is here called [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). It always  discards the fractional part.

That's why `140/150` gives you always `0`, not `0.9333...`

.NET has 3 type of division. From C# Spec in [`7.7.2 Division operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- Integer division
- Floating-point division
- Decimal division

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands.

If you want to display it like `0.93`, you need to cast *one of* your integer to floating point number.

For example;

```
140d / 150 // 0.933333...
140 / 150d // 0.933333...
140d / 150d // 0.933333...
140.0 / 150 // 0.933333...
140 / 150.0 // 0.933333...
140.0 / 150.0 // 0.933333...
```

Comment: So - 150 / 140 becomes 140d / 150d, or even 140d / 150 if you're feeling lazy - only one operand has to be non-integer...

Comment: @MartinMilan Like I did in `140d` or `150d`? Both operand could be a floating point number also but one is enough. That's why I said _one of_ in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Name;
            string Surname;
            int Maths;
            int Science;
            int IT;
            float Average;


            Name = edtName.Text;
            Surname = edtSurname.Text;
            Maths = int.Parse(edtMaths.Text);
            Science = int.Parse(edtScience.Text);
            IT = int.Parse(edtIT.Text);
            Average = ((((float)Maths/150.0)*100)+(((float)IT/150.0)*100)+(((float)Science/150.0)*100))/3;

            if (Average >= 75)
            {
                lblOutput.Text += "You shall recieve a bursary!";
            }
```

try it

Comment: isn't decimal better?